# spring-cloud : Override Ribbon configuration to achieve Zone Affinity

Tags: spring-cloud

I want to achieve Zone Affinity during load balancing. In the logs i see '`DynamicServerListLoadBalancer`' being used and according to the behavior it looks round robin rule is active.

I created custom configuration to override `RibbonClientConfiguration`, but its not working. Is this correct?

```
public class CustomConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private IClientConfig config;

    @Autowired
    ServerListFilter<Server> filter;

    @Bean
    public ILoadBalancer ribbonLoadBalancer(IClientConfig config,
            ServerListFilter<Server> filter) {
        ZoneAwareLoadBalancer<Server> balancer = new ZoneAwareLoadBalancer<>(config);
        balancer.setFilter(filter);
        return balancer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerListFilter<Server> ribbonServerListFilter(IClientConfig config) {
        ZonePreferenceServerListFilter filter = new ZonePreferenceServerListFilter();
        filter.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
        return filter;
    }
}

@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "custom", configuration = CustomConfiguration.class)
public class CustomApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: So, a `ZoneAwareLoadBalancer` extends `DynamicServerListLoadBalancer`, so things you see in the logs may very well be from `DynamicServerListLoadBalancer`.  Changing the load balancer does not change the default rule which is round robin, it should just round robin among instances in the zone.

Comment: I have two Nodes (Node 1 & 2)  where the services are deployed. The client of the services is running in Node 1 and I want the client to always pick the service from Node 1, if the service is up.

Comment: I think you would need to write a custom rule to get that sort of Primary/Secondary behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I dont see Zone Affinity working. I added one more service to Node 1 which made two services on Node 1. Now, when client on Node 1 sent the requests, I thought it would be between the two services on Node 1 but it went between services on Node 1 and 2 in round-robin fashion. Does this mean Zone Affinity is not supported out of the box by spring-cloud.

Comment: Zone affinity means affinity for servers based in the same AWS Zone.  Where are these servers deployed?

Comment: Currently I'm using two desktop machines to get my understanding.

Comment: So how is the "zone" of each `Server` defined or determined by the load balancer? Just having them use different host names won't do anything out of the box (how would the client know that those hosts were in different "zones"?).